# Relation between left and right Jordan forms

Tags: jordan-normal-form

If I compute the right Jordan canonical decomposition of a matrix $A$, i.e. I get $$A = VJV^{-1},$$
will I be able to get the left canonical form from it without any further computation?

The right Jordan canonical form is the when where the diagonal right above the diagonal of $J$ is made by zero or one.
The left one is the same but the diagonal made by zero or one is the one right below the diagonal of $J$.

Comment: It is simple, the new matrix $V$ is the inverse of the transpose of the old $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \lambda \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$