# How can I guarantee that all the number of generalized eigenvectors are equal to the algebraic multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, block-matrices, generalized-eigenvector

I have found many questions in the Stack but, I couldn't find what I want...
Since my major is physics, I'm not good at the terms in mathematics.
So it was hard to reach understanding Jordan normal form..
If you can answer with an easy approach, I'll express my gratitude in advance.

For the sake of asking in detail, I take an example that the characteritic of a $5\times 5$ matirx $A$ be $p(t)=(t-\lambda)^5$. (the algebraic multiplicity is 5.)

In this case, I can find the linearly independent eigenvectors by finding how many linearly independent rows or columns is in $A-\lambda I$. Let the number of independent rows or columns in $A-\lambda I$ is 3. Then, The number of Jordan block is 3. Following this manner up to $(A-\lambda I)^5$, I can find the size of each block.

Here is my question. Can I guarantee that there are totally 5 generalized eigenvectors? If I assume that there is the excess or lack of generalized eigenvectors, what happens? I think that the contradictions arise definitely.

Comment: one simple thing:  if you calculate the minimal polynomial instead,   and the eigenvalue $\lambda$   occurs as $(x- \lambda)^k,$   then the largest Jordan block for $\lambda$ is size $k$ by $k.$    Anyway,

Comment: I have found how to derive the minimal polynomial... However I couldn't understand... is there  any good doccument for the derivation of minimal polynomial?

Comment: My advice is to do many problems for which all the matrix entries and eigenvalues are integers. The practice that will help is taking such a matrix $A,$   finding a matrix $P$  of all integers such that $P^{-1} A P = J$ is in Jordan form.   I've answered a bunch of such questions, I guess I can put links to them as an answer

Comment: Every $n\times n$ matrix with (real or) complex entries has $n$ generalized eigenvectors (over the complex numbers). If $A$ has Jordan form $J$, then there's a matrix $P$ with $P^{-1}AP=J$, and the columns of $P$ are the (generalized) eigenvectors.

Comment: To Gerry Myerson. As far as I know, any matrix has Jordan forms. My question is about whether every $n\times n$ matrix has indeed  $n$ generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes, every $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has a Jordan form $J$. And the relation between $A$ and $J$ is $P^{-1}AP=J$ for some invertible matrix $P$. And the columns of $P$, of which there are $n$, are the generalized eigenvectors of $A$. So $A$ has $n$ generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: When I wrote, "If $A$ has Jordan form $J$ ...," that was to be interpreted as "If we let $J$ be the Jordan form of $A$ ...." It wasn't meant to suggest that there are matrices that don't have a Jordan form.

Comment: To Gerry Myerson. Oh! we can think like that! I like the logic because it is very simple! thank you so much!!

Comment: The number of Jordan blocks corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the nullity of (A-$\lambda$I) and not its rank.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of the following matrix is $p(x)=x^5$, and its minimal polynomial is the same:
$$
       A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
               0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
               0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
               0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
               0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
               0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
               \end{array}
         \right]
$$
Indeed, it is easy to verify that $A^5=0$ and $A^4\ne 0$ by applying powers of $A$ to the column vector with all zeroes, except for a $1$ in the bottom place:
$$
            \left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right].
$$
So the minimal polynomial for $A$ is the same as its characteristic polynomial $p(x)=x^5$. The Jordan canonical form is designed to deal with this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions I had noticed in this area.

[Jordan decomposition - help with calculation of transformationmatrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586921/jordan-decomposition-help-with-calculation-of-transformationmatrices/2586930#2586930)

[Relation between left and right Jordan forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619445/relation-between-left-and-right-jordan-forms/2619682#2619682)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646324/if-matrix-a-beginbmatrix100-101-010-endbmatrix-then-a50/2646408#2646408

[When is the following matrix diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657633/when-is-the-following-matrix-diagonalizable/2657907#2657907)

[Similarity of $3\times3$ matrices via Jordan canonical form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663792/similarity-of-3-times3-matrices-via-jordan-canonical-form/2663813#2663813)

[Solutions for a 3x3 ODE system with one eigenvalues (m=3).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664403/solutions-for-a-3x3-ode-system-with-one-eigenvalues-m-3/2664925#2664925)

[What is the mistake in my matrix power formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665177/what-is-the-mistake-in-my-matrix-power-formula/2665204#2665204)

[Eigenvectors calculation: a defective matrix, a zero matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666568/eigenvectors-calculation-a-defective-matrix-a-zero-matrix/2666609#2666609)

[Ununderstanded Jordan normal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667887/ununderstanded-jordan-normal-form)

[Problem with generalized eigenvectors in a 3x3 matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667609/problem-with-generalized-eigenvectors-in-a-3x3-matrix/2667964#2667964)

[What is the minimal polynomial of A?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667415/what-is-the-minimal-polynomial-of-a/2668047#2668047)  good one

[Jordan basis unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671276/jordan-basis-unique/2674033#2674033)  vary generalized!

[Finding Jordan-normal form of a special $n\times n$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674971/finding-jordan-normal-form-of-a-special-n-times-n-matrix/2675153#2675153)

[how to define a function over a Jordanizable matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689641/how-to-define-a-function-over-a-jordanizable-matrix/2689664#2689664)

[What values of $a$ make matrix $A$ diagonalisable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706368/what-values-of-a-make-matrix-a-diagonalisable/2706665#2706665)

[Finding nilpotent and diagonalizable operators for a linear transformation $T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722246/finding-nilpotent-and-diagonalizable-operators-for-a-linear-transformation-t/2722317#2722317) (Jordan-Chevalley)

[Matrix in canonical form of an orthogonal transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742114/matrix-in-canonical-form-of-an-orthogonal-transformation/2743574#2743574)  Real J form

[Diagonalize matrix with complex eigenvalues by real basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744284/diagonalize-matrix-with-complex-eigenvalues-by-real-basis/2744986#2744986) Real J form

[Jordan normal form (Basis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786604/jordan-normal-form-basis/2786627#2786627)  ker W^3 \ ker W^2

[Determine size or number of jordan blocks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787643/determine-size-or-number-of-jordan-blocks/2787724#2787724)  ker W^3 \ ker W^2

[Is this a correct basis for the Jordan normal form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146407/is-this-a-correct-basis-for-the-jordan-normal-form)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll read all of them! If I get several questions though, I'll ask you again.

Comment: I have read several sites you recommended. Unfortunately, finding generalized eigenvectors for such specific examples is not what I want to know... What I want to know exactly is whether we can find always $n$ generalized eigenvectors in a $n\times n$ matrix.